# Does band structure diagram tell anything about position of the particle?

Tags: solid-state-physics

1. What is the physical interpretation of the electronic band structure diagram and wave vector $k$ in solid-state physics? Does $k$ tell something about the direction of moving electron/particle?
2. The wavevector $k$ is a Fourier transform of position $x$. Can we tell that at a specific point of $k$ the electron will be at a specific $x$ position?

Comment: No, there is no position information. Bloch states extend throughout the crystal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. When you construct a band structure, you are constructing it based off of the wave-like states of the electron in the crystal. As Jon pointed out, the wavefunctions of electrons in a repeating lattice are often formulated conveniently as plane wave states modulated by the periodicity of the crystal, known as Bloch wavefunctions. By the nature of plane waves, these are not localized to a position in space.

Another way to think about it is that the uncertainly principle mandates that an exact knowledge of momentum corresponds to an infinite uncertainty in position. Therefore, if we know the momentum for an electron given by its k value in a band diagram, we cannot assign it a spatial position.